# Amazon SageMaker ScriptMode Long Python Wheel Build Times for CUDA Components

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, python-wheel

I use PyTorch estimator with SageMaker to train/fine-tune my Graph Neural Net on multi-GPU machines.

The `requirements.txt` that gets installed into the Estimator container, has lines like:

```
torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu113.html
torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu113.html
torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu113.html
torch-spline-conv -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu113.html
```

When SageMaker installs these requirements in the Estimator on the endpoint, it takes ~**2 hrs** to build the wheel. It takes only seconds on a local Linux box.

SageMaker Estimator:

PyTorch v1.10
CUDA 11.x
Python 3.8
Instance: ml.p3.16xlarge

I have noticed the same issue with other wheel-based components that require CUDA.

I have also tried building a Docker container on p3.16xlarge and running that on SageMaker, but it was unable to recognize the instance GPUs

Anything I can do to cut down these build times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to augment the stock estimator image with the right components and then it can be run in the SageMaker script mode:

```
FROM    763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.10-gpu-py38

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.tx
```

The key is to make sure `nvidia` runtime is used at build time, so `daemon.json` needs to be configured accordingly:

```json
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

This is still not a complete solution, because viability of the build for SageMaker depends on the host where the build is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Pip install for the package needs [compiling][1] which will take time. Not sure but on your local instance it may have built the first time. One workaround is to extend the base [container][2] with the below (one time cost) and use it in SageMaker Estimator

ADD 
./requirements.txt 
/tmp/packages/

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/packages/requirements.txt
[1]: https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/blob/master/setup.py
[2]: https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/pytorch/training/docker/1.10/py3/cu113/Dockerfile.sagemaker.gpu

Comment: Thanks. Tried that - didn’t work. The resulting container refused to recognize GPUs

Comment: Which exact FROM did you use in the dockerfile? Note that there's a CPU and GPU container, you might have extended the CPU container by mistake.

Comment: Should be: 
763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.10.2-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04-e3     
Based on: https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md

Comment: Oh yes. Not quite this one but the one with GPU support: FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.9-gpu-py38.

Comment: Sample showing the container + bootstrap - https://github.com/anoop-ml/sagemaker_pytorch_scatter